# Listview change selection color

Tags: c++, uwp, c++-cx

How can I change a selection color of item in ListView? Also I would like to change size of border around the item. By default the background color when the item is selected is green and the frame is very thick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the selected color and border by using ItemContainerStyle. **Right-click** your ListView in the designer -> **Edit Additional Template** -> **Edit Item Container Style** -> **Edit a copy**, then the default ItemContainerStyle will be generated. There is a **SelectedBackground** property from the ListViewItemPresenter, you can set it as other color you want, in this case,  the selected color will change. In addition, if you want to change the size of border when you select the item, there is a Selected visual state which represents Selected state, you can reset the **RevealBorderThickness** and **RevealBorderBrush** properties in this state. For example:

.xaml:

```
<Page.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="ListViewItemContainerStyle1" TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}"/>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemBackground}"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemForeground}"/>
            <Setter Property="TabNavigation" Value="Local"/>
            <Setter Property="IsHoldingEnabled" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="12,0,12,0"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemMinWidth}"/>
            <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemMinHeight}"/>
            <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="False"/>
            <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="{StaticResource UseSystemFocusVisuals}"/>
            <Setter Property="FocusVisualMargin" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                        <ListViewItemPresenter x:Name="Root" FocusVisualPrimaryThickness="0" CheckBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemCheckBrush}" ContentMargin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" CheckBoxBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemCheckBoxBrush}" ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}" CheckMode="{ThemeResource ListViewItemCheckMode}" DragOpacity="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragThemeOpacity}" DisabledOpacity="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDisabledThemeOpacity}" DragBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragBackground}" DragForeground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragForeground}" FocusBorderBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemFocusBorderBrush}" FocusVisualMargin="{TemplateBinding FocusVisualMargin}" FocusSecondaryBorderBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemFocusSecondaryBorderBrush}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Control.IsTemplateFocusTarget="True" PressedBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemBackgroundPressed}" PlaceholderBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackground}" PointerOverForeground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemForegroundPointerOver}" PointerOverBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemBackgroundPointerOver}" RevealBorderThickness="{ThemeResource MenuFlyoutItemRevealBorderThickness}" ReorderHintOffset="{ThemeResource ListViewItemReorderHintThemeOffset}" RevealBorderBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemRevealBorderBrush}" RevealBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemRevealBackground}" SelectedForeground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemForegroundSelected}" SelectionCheckMarkVisualEnabled="{ThemeResource ListViewItemSelectionCheckMarkVisualEnabled}" SelectedBackground="Red" SelectedPressedBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemBackgroundSelectedPressed}" SelectedPointerOverBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemBackgroundSelectedPointerOver}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                        <VisualState.Setters>
                                            <Setter Target="Root.RevealBorderThickness" Value="2"/>
                                            <Setter Target="Root.RevealBorderBrush" Value="Green"/>
                                        </VisualState.Setters>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                        <VisualState.Setters>
                                            <Setter Target="Root.(RevealBrush.State)" Value="PointerOver"/>
                                            <Setter Target="Root.RevealBorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemRevealBorderBrushPointerOver}"/>
                                        </VisualState.Setters>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="PointerOverSelected">
                                        <VisualState.Setters>
                                            <Setter Target="Root.(RevealBrush.State)" Value="PointerOver"/>
                                            <Setter Target="Root.RevealBorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemRevealBorderBrushPointerOver}"/>
                                        </VisualState.Setters>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="PointerOverPressed">
                                        <VisualState.Setters>
                                            <Setter Target="Root.(RevealBrush.State)" Value="Pressed"/>
                                            <Setter Target="Root.RevealBorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemRevealBorderBrushPressed}"/>
                                        </VisualState.Setters>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                        <VisualState.Setters>
                                            <Setter Target="Root.(RevealBrush.State)" Value="Pressed"/>
                                            <Setter Target="Root.RevealBorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemRevealBorderBrushPressed}"/>
                                        </VisualState.Setters>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="PressedSelected">
                                        <VisualState.Setters>
                                            <Setter Target="Root.(RevealBrush.State)" Value="Pressed"/>
                                            <Setter Target="Root.RevealBorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemRevealBorderBrushPressed}"/>
                                        </VisualState.Setters>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="DisabledStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Enabled"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                        <VisualState.Setters>
                                            <Setter Target="Root.RevealBorderThickness" Value="0"/>
                                        </VisualState.Setters>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        </ListViewItemPresenter>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Page.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <ListView Width="300" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListViewItemContainerStyle1}">
            <ListViewItem>123</ListViewItem>
            <ListViewItem>234</ListViewItem>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks! Actually I want to change size of a frame around the item.

Comment: Can you show more details about the frame around the item?